# Guidelines for building tape delimited MTB courses

Tags: mountain-bike, track-racing

There are a few vacant lots around where I live and last weekend, I built a small (170m) tape delimited course.

Some of the kids in the neighborhood rode in it. I also worked out in it, going full tilt for 30 minutes (ie. 36 laps in 30min, 6.2km). Some portions were up a grade, others went down a grade. There were a few areas that were quite tight to turn around in, but otherwise, it seemed alright. This lead me to search for possible standards in this area.

I was wondering if there were guidelines or standards for building such courses in terms of lane width, turning areas and such?

**Edit #1**

Here's what our course looked like:

[image]

The corner in this image was quite hard for everyone - which could just be testament for our skill level :)

The goal isn't to be a UCI event, just looking to give my kids some more experience riding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Have a look at UCI's MTB rules at http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/16/72/76/MTBReglementsENG_English.pdf

Look for "course marking".

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Apparently, my course was indeed, too narrow <4m wide :)

Comment: You can build/mark a course any way you like. If you want it to be part of a UCI event though you have to go by the book. In any case, reading the guidelines is always fun.

Comment: Some of my local forest trails tracks are being widened (as in cutting down trees) to accommodate the wide (800-850mm)handle bars that are now fashionable because idiots that think they know how to ride keep getting handle bar strike.... Don't make it 4 meters wide everywhere, a MTBer needs to be able ride a 1 meter wide (At handle bar height) trail.

Comment: @mattnz see my edit which shows the type of course I was making, and the area which will hopefully host other courses during this summer :)

Comment: @cherouvim see my edit which shows the course I was referring to.